# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Poster' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

вот сайт https://moviecollection.netlify.app вроде все работает как нужно выдает ответ адекватный(запрос фильма только на англ.) но есть ошибка в консоли которая меня очень муляет, уже второй день над ней сижу, что я делю не так подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.
Скрин ошибки: [image: Cannot read property]

Comment: Опишите вопрос подробнее. Не понятно что вы делаете. Не понятно в каких ситуациях возникает ошибка. Приложите код. А в ошибке чётко написано: *Не могу прочитать свойство у undefined*

Comment: Когда в input  пишем запрос фильма выдает эту ошибку код можно посмотреть если перейти по ссылке https://moviecollection.netlify.app или здесь https://github.com/SynytcaEvgen/Movie_Collection.git  ввести запрос и в косоли будет эта ошибка

Comment: Ну так у вас в `count.Search[i] === undefined`

Comment: Если count.Search[i] === undefined то почему тогда работает function CounterBuild(count) и строит все карточки фильмов. Я вот подумываю не скрыт ответ в асинхронности. Или я что то не понимаю

Comment: @YevhenSynytsia выложите на stackoverflow код, с которым вы не справляетесь, укажите где у вас в этом коде вопросы

Comment: Дело в том что я не знаю где ошибка в коде поэтому дал ссылку на сайт https://moviecollection.netlify.app  на репозиторий github.com/SynytcaEvgen/Movie_Collection.git. Код работает вот только ошибка в консоли. Мне кажется так легче смотреть баги если нет я выложу на stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На 69 строке movie_loader.js цикл:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= count.Search.length; i++){
```

В условии больше или равно <= . Соотвествено цикл выполняется на один раз болше чем надо и падает.

Comment: Спасибо большое